# What is the benefit of using a technique with low duty cycle?

Tags: pulse, duty-cycle

there are some techniques used into Wireless network on chip, Ultra Wide Band Interconnect is one, I have to ask the benefit of low duty cycle pulse?

I think the target of communication is to maximise the duty cycle not to minimise!!!!

But, in some papers, i found that: Ultra-Wideband interconnect (UWB-I) has the unique features of high bandwidth and low-duty cycle pulse, which make it an attractive solution for high data rate multi-processor. Any explanation pls?

Comment: Try leaving a link to what you read so that folk can understand where you are coming from.

Comment: I just want to understand the meaning of low duty cycle in communication, and it's benefits.

Comment: I read "Design of multi-channel wireless NoC to improve on-chip communication capacity!" Dan Zhao @Andyaka

Comment: Why on earth should I purchase this article - maybe you have a hyperlink that takes me to a copy that is free and readable?

Comment: I suggest you copy/photograph the script/words/pictures that are confusing you and post them as an edit to your question.

Comment: "I don't want" let's get that clear. Use a photograph upload service (maybe imgur) and post a link to the photo as a comment.

Comment: @Liza bb8: just a guess: maybe low duty cycle is a benefit because the medium (frequency band) can be used by many (not just two ("multi-processor")) parties (time-division multiplexing).

Comment: But for high data rate there is necessity to use as possible a technique allows to maximise the data transformation not to minimise the percentage of period that signal is active (low duty cycle)!!! @Curd

Comment: @Liza bb8: but 1% of 1Gbps is still 10Mbps and might be enough and enables 99 others to communicate too (ideally). What use is it if only **one** can talk with 1Gbps and all others can't at all?

Comment: That is logical, but with low duty cycle and multi users, it can causes high latency which is contrary to what the author said @Curd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You're application of duty cycle to UWB is confused...

[image]

Ultra-wide band works *in the time domain* by expressing information as a very narrow pulse (fast edge *rate*). This is *by definition* a *low duty cycle* because the percentage of time the signal is active relative to at rest is very small (see the right panel in the figure above). If it were not, the signal would look like the left panel above and would have much less frequency content and therefore *much less bandwidth*.

### That is the power of ultra-wide band! Cool!

UWB works because the sharp non-smooth transitions in the time domain create broad-spectrum (wide band) signals in the frequency domain. There is literally no way to draw a "high duty cycle UWB" waveform as you imagine it. It wouldn't be wide-band anymore.  You are likely confusing *pulse repetition rate* with duty cycle in your mental model.

### Pulse and Data Rates

> What is the relation between low duty cycle pulse and high data rate

[image]

The waveform on the left above has the spectrum content of the "NB" line below. The waveform on the right above has the spectrum content of the "UWB" line below.

See how much more spectrum is involved? A LOT MORE! And there is a core axiom in information theory that says the data rate is constrained by bandwidth (width of the spectrum). So UWB has a lot of spectrum and therefore can sustain the highest data rates.

Comment: I disagree that "This is by definition a low duty cycle". Also it doesn't explain any benefit (cf. original question). If duty cylce goes down as band width goes up, there is no gain in data rate.

Comment: @Curd -- Your logic assumes that those differences cancel out, which is not true for UWB at higher edge-rates. The duty cycle is decreasing at a much lower rate than the bandwidth is increasing for linearly increasing edge-rate. This is because UWB wave-shapes are inherently non-linear (that's where the the broad spectral content comes from).

Comment: @DrFriedParts pleaese what are you mean with percentage of time that the signal is active , which event is reffered when the signal is active?

Comment: @Liza - See the UWB figure at the top-right of the answer? The signal is "active" any time it is not on the y=0 line (horizontally flat regions) of that graph.